# select record that group_concat() contain a char

Tags: mysql, group-concat

How to select `mystatus` field that contain only 0

```
select c.id,count(*),
       group_concat(distinct(r.status not in ('Done','None'))) as mystatus
from cases c inner join reports r 
on (c.id = r.parent_id and r.parent_type = 'Cases' and r.deleted = 0)
where c.deleted = 0 
and c. status <> 'Late'
group by c.id
```

Result look like this, but I want to select for only `mystatus` contain 0.

```
ID  count(*)  mystatus
A   1         0
B   7         0,1
C   2         0
```

It should be select records ID A and C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a HAVING clause.

```
select c.id,count(*),
       group_concat(distinct(r.status not in ('Done','None'))) as mystatus
from cases c inner join reports r 
on (c.id = r.parent_id and r.parent_type = 'Cases' and r.deleted = 0)
where c.deleted = 0 
and c. status <> 'Late'
group by c.id
having mystatus = '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `HAVING` clause:

```
select c.id,count(*),
       group_concat(distinct(r.status not in ('Done','None'))) as mystatus
from cases c inner join reports r 
on (c.id = r.parent_id and r.parent_type = 'Cases' and r.deleted = 0)
where c.deleted = 0 and c. status <> 'Late'
group by c.id
having count(case when r.status <> 0 then 1 end) = 0
```

The predicate of the `HAVING` clause uses *conditional aggregation* to filter out `c.id` groups containing *at least one* record with `r.status <> 0`.

**Note:** Use `r.status <> '0'` in case `r.status` field is of character type.

Comment: Won't you need  apostrophes since my status is a string column?

Comment: @sagi See the note I added just before your comment!

Comment: Thank you so much :) I use `having` but not like this. 
I add `having mystatus = '0'` and it's work.